# Using np.where, langdetect in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, sentiment-analysis

I want to add a new column in dataframe, which will paste the data from another column if it is written in English, and paste nothing if it is not in English using langdetect library.

```
df['lyrics_english'] = np.where(detect(df["lyrics"]) == 'en', df["lyrics"], '')
```

I hope, the meaning is clear. But I have Error like this.

```
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/pythontask/example", line 128, in <module>
    df['lyrics_english'] = np.where(detect(df["lyrics"]) == 'en', df["lyrics"], '')
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\langdetect\detector_factory.py", line 129, in detect
    detector.append(text)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\langdetect\detector.py", line 104, in append
    text = self.URL_RE.sub(' ', text)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

If I type

```
df['lyrics_english'] = np.where(detect(df["lyrics"]) == 'en', 0, '')
```

there is again the same Error, smth linked with AppData. What can I do?

Comment: What's the content of `detect` function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a function via `df.apply`, including the conditional decision:

```
df['lyrics_english'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.lyrics if detect(x.lyrics)=='en' else '', axis=1)
```

Or you could use the `map` command on the Series that forms the `lyrics` column:

```
df['lyrics_english'] = df['lyrics'].map(lambda x: x if detect(x)=='en' else '')
```

The second approach seems to be faster on an unrealistic example I tried and not using the original langdetect.detect function.

Comment: Thank you David Wierichs. But my problem is still unresolved. Something connected with  the lyb file.

Comment: Sorry, I kinda missed the point there, correct. @YOLO's answer is a good route in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess might be due to some non-string values like `nan`, you can try:

```
df['lyrics_english'] = np.where(detect(df["lyrics"].fillna("")) == 'en', df["lyrics"], '')
```

If this doesn't work, then you need to look into `df["lyrics"].unique()` and understand what's going on there.

Comment: Thank you too @YOLO. But there is still the same error. df['lyrics'].unique()   consists of about 8000 songs lyrics, I don't know what can be wrong with that, if ,with your code, we use fillna. Lyrics are either NaN or strings․